# Set the parameters of Word2Vec for a practical example

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I have a database containing about 2.8 million texts (more precisely tweets, so they are short texts). I put clean tweets (removing hashtags, tags, stop words...) in a list of lists of tokens called `sentences` (so it contains a list of tokens for each tweet).

After these steps, if I write

`model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)`

I obtain a vocabulary of about 400,000 words.

This was just an attempt, I would need some help to set the parameters (`size`, `window`, `min_count`, `workers`, `sg`) of `Word2Vec` in the most appropriate and consistent way.

Consider that my goal is to use

`model.most_similar(terms)` (where `terms` is a list of words)

to find, within the list of lists of tokens `sentences`, the words most similar to those contained in `terms`.

The words in `terms` belong to the same topic and I would like to see if there are other words within the texts that could have to do with the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the usual approach is:

- Start with the defaults, to get things initially working at a baseline level, perhaps only on a faster-to-work-with subset of the data.
- Develop an objective way to determine whether one model is better than another, for your purposes. This might start as a bunch of ad hoc, manual comparisons of results for some representative probes - but *should* become a process that can automatically score each variant model, giving a higher score to the 'better' model according to some qualitative, repeatable process.
- Either tinker with parameters one-by-one, or run a large search over many permutations, to find which model does best on your scoring.

Separately: the quality of word2vec results is almost always improved by discarding the very rarest words, such as those appearing only once. (The default value of `min_count` is `5` for good reason.)

The algorithm can't make good word-vectors from words that only appear once, or a few times. It *needs* multiple, contrasting examples of its usage. But, given the typical Zipfian distribution of word usages in a corpus, there are a lot of such rare words. Discarding them speeds training, shrinks the model, & eliminates what's essentially 'noise' from the training of other words - leaving those remaining word-vectors much better. (If you really need vectors for such words – gather more data.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is not easy for me to focus on the meaning of the parameters. For example: if ```size``` is ```100``` by default, how do I know if I could have better results by increasing or decreasing it, considering the amount and type of data I am working on? In other words: yes, I have to test various combinations of parameters. But in which direction do I have to go to choose them?

Comment: Well, you have to have some idea, for some subset of the data/words, what kinds of `most_similar()` results you'd like to see. What results are *useful* for whatever reason you're doing this? You then run multiple models and compare their results on cases where you have strong expectations of what good results are - and when a model does well on those, you give some conditional, qualified trust to all the other results it gives as being somewhat useful (unless/until you can confirm it could have done better).

Comment: That process if often ad-hoc at 1st – just looking over alternate model's results for what vaguely seems better. But the only way to tunr parameters is to have some standard for testing whether the results from one or another model are 'better'. And generally you want to find, or create, some 'gold standard' of *good results* for scoring models, to replace that ad-hoc by-eye process with something that can be automated, repeated, and improved over time.